# Google App Script "Exceeded Execution time" on simple function

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, while-loop, google-sheets-formula

I am writing an App Script embedded in Google sheets so the maximum execution time is 30s. When I try to run the function it always returns an error saying the execution time was exceeded. However when I run the function in a online compiler for javascript it takes less than a second to run. I am pretty sure that the problem are the two embedded while loops, but I don't know how I could get rid of them without sacrificing the functionality of my function.
I am also surprised that it takes so long to run this function as it seems quite simple to me. Is app script this slow?
Can someone please explain why it takes so long and what steps I could take to improve the speed of my function without sacrificing functionality?

```
function counter(input,input2) {
var mx=input[0];
  var my=input[1];
  var links=input2[0];
  var unten=input2[1];


  // distance
  var xmin=0.3;
  var ymin=0.3;

  // size of object
  var xlength=mx;
  var ylength=my;

  var counter=0
  var pvx1={}
  var pvy1={}

  //Startposition x
  var xPosition=xmin;

  
  while (xPosition<=(unten-xlength-xmin)){
    var yPosition=ymin;
    while (yPosition<=(links-ylength-ymin)){
    
      counter=counter+1;
      yPosition=yPosition+ylength;
    
    }
    xPosition=xPosition+xlength;
  }
  

return counter
}
```

I'm trying to stack rectangles into a bigger rectangle and count the amount that fits in. I'm starting in the bottom left corner and fill up each column form bottom to top and then continue in the row.
For a later application I need more than just the number of rectangles I can fit in, I also need their position within the other rectangle.